# pdo sqlite rowcount() returns 0

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, rowcount

pdo sqlite rowcount() returns only 0

what's the problem ?

The code is :

```php
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.db',null,null, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE password=:pass";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('pass', $_POST['pssowd'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(['pass'=>$_POST['pssowd']]);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();  
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
/*
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["password"]=> string(2) "dz" }
*/
var_dump($_POST['pssowd']);
#string(2) "dz"
if ($count >0) {
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "Wrong Data";
}
```

Comment: you don't need this rowCount(). you already have fetch(). $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if ($user). there is no use for rowCount

Comment: Should it return a value different than 0? What do you want to use that method for?

Comment: for login user  !

Comment: I have a solution to get around the problem
 FETCH DATA
and use Comparison Operators

Comment: The documentation of `rowCount()` specifically says that it may not work for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: And then it says that it always returns `0` for SQLite.